# Fechar ou não uma execução quando houver erro PDOException?

Tags: php, pdo

Ao implementar o PDOException há necessidade de usar die ou exit para finalizar a execução em caso de erros? ou basta retornar um "echo" informando o erro e deixar a execução do script seguir?

Minha implementação atual:

```
define("HOST", 'localhost');
define("USER", 'root');
define("PASS", '');
define("NAME", 'script');

//Conectamos ao banco de dados
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".HOST.";dbname=".NAME.";charset=utf8", "".USER."", "".PASS."");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Erro ao conectar no banco de dados");
}

// Função basica para gerenciamento PDO
function sql($db, $q, $params, $return) {
    
    try {

        //prepara a querry
        $stmt = $db->prepare($q);

        //executa a query
        $stmt->execute($params);
        
        // retorna no formato solicitado pela variavel
        if ($return == "rows") {
            return $stmt->fetch();
        }elseif ($return == "rowsall") {
            return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }elseif ($return == "count") {
            return $stmt->rowCount();
        }elseif( $return == "lastid"){
            return $db->lastInsertId();
        }
        
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        
        echo "DataBase Erro: ".$e->getMessage();
        die();
        
    }catch(Exception $e) {
        
        echo "Erro Geral: ".$e->getMessage();
        die();
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Se der erro no banco, faz sentido executar o restante do script?

Comment: @Woss e quanto ao Try/catch, e necessário usar em todas as query? como está na função acima?

Answer (score -1):

Como diz no comentário do Woss: se pergunte se faz sentido o script executar se der erro no banco. Provavelmente não, então é interessante finalizar a execução.